# How to build Json from unknown parameters and unknown number of them in java?

Tags: java, json, reflection, jersey, jackson

I have different commands :

```
Command1(String name, Integer age) extends BasicCommand
Command2(String address, Info cityInfo)  extends BasicCommandWithException// Info is a class containing 2 fields : city name and city size
Command3(CountryInfo countryInfo, String continent) extends BasicCommandWithCityNameAndException

[BasicCommandWithCityNameAndException extends BasicCommandWithException extends BasicCommand]
```

I can't add a new abstract class for extension, so I thought of a wrapper that will contain a command and the parameters. I want to be able to convert the passed parameters to a json to I will have something like this:

```
Wrapper c = new Wrapper(Command1 ("hello", 55))
cityInfo cit = new cityInfo("city", 1000)
Wrapper b = new Wrapper(Command2("myAddress", cit))

String x = c.getJsonFromParams
will print:
{
   "name" : "hello",
   "age" : 55
}

String y = b.getJsonFromParams
will print:
{
    "address" : "myAddress",
    "cityInfo": {
                 "cityName" : "city",
                 "citySize" : 1000
                }  
}
```

have no idea where to start from.
I can't figure out how to pass these parameters as thy can change (the type, the number of them etc)
Can you please advise?

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using one of the popular JSON marshalling libraries? Jackson: `String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(command)`

Comment: but isn't 'command' needs to be a class? for example if I pass Command(x,y,z) i will have to create class A {x,y,z} and if I pass Command(r,t) i will have to create Class B {r,t} - how can I create these classes in runtime? I don't know which commands will pass

Comment: No, 'command' would be an object not a class. `Command command = new Command1("Ed", 21); String json  = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(command);`

Comment: NB your examples seem to be missing the `new` keyword. And semicolons.  `Wrapper c = new Wrapper(new Command1 ("hello", 55))`

Comment: just fixed it. thank you - i will try it now :)